# Admob gradle dependency

Tags: android, build, gradle, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to move to gradle in my project and I've got problem while install admob

```
dependency
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '12.0'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'){
        exclude module: 'com.google.ads'
    }
    compile 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.19'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

And I am geting

> Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;

in my libs folder only one 
GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar

Comment: Please do not use the Jar, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using `Google Play services` , then remove the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk jar` from lib folder

You can also exclude the ads from play service like this, to continue with jar.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'){
    exclude module:'gms.ads'
}
```

But you need to upgrade soon.

Note : **Deprecated**. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.
Read these links

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration
   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadplay

Comment: I am moving to gradle. So if i remove GoogleAdMobAdsSdk jar i wll have to rewrite some code  for example AdListener  became abstract class